# How to Make Custom-Length Jumper Wires

Tags: hardware, microcontrollers

I am prototyping a Wi-Fi thermometer with an ESP8266 and an HT11, it works on the breadboard (!) and now I am designing a 3D printable cabinet. I would like the final thing to be completely dis-mountable, so I am avoiding soldering.

The ESP8266 and the HT11 come with pins that I need to connect. I can use female-female jumper wires, but the standard sizes (I see only 10 and 20 cm on sale) are too long for me.

Any suggestions on how to make a a short female-female jumper cable? I'd say I need a 2 or 3 cm long cable maximum.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is simply about cable assembly and not IoT. But what you need is just a couple of simple wire, crimp and connector case, like these: [2-4 pin dupont connectors](https://c.76.my/Malaysia/2-4-pin-female-dupont-connector-crimp-pin-2-54mm-pitch-littlecraft-1601-18-littlecraft@1.jpg). These are called dupont connectors and here is a tutorial if you need one. [tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Fitting-Dupont-Connectors/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a generic electronics prototyping question rather than a question about the Internet of Things.

Comment: thanks a lot for this input! I missed the fact that these are ordinary `2.54 mm Dupont connectors`, now that I know their name a whole world is open ...

Comment: about closing: ok if is OT, but was tagged as `hardware` in the old fashioned meaning of the word.

Comment: Tags are used to narrow the scope inside the topic of IoT. [tag:hardware] exists on half a dozen stack exchange site I think, yet your question would be OT there.